Why are some faces disappearing from on the camera view?
I was following a YouTube tutorial: https://youtu.be/XWv1Ajc3tfU and when I tried to see the result from the camera and some parts of the black hole's ring were missing. When I checked it from the viewport, everything is okay. Is there a way to fix this?



Select the camera and in the Data panel > Lens > tweak the Clip Start and End values?

Omg, I changed the clip end into 300 and it actually worked! Thanks a lot! @moonboots
